# Why float point literal 3.14f is represented by a 64-bit value 0x40091EB860000000 in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const float PI = 3.14f;
//const float PI = 3.14;

float getPI() {
  return PI;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(float));
  return 0;
}
```

sizeof(float) is 4. But in LLVM bytecode, 3.14f is represented by a 64-bit double [0x40091EB860000000](http://binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=40091EB860000000).

```
@PI = constant float 0x40091EB860000000, align 4

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define float @getPI() #0 {
entry:
  ret float 0x40091EB860000000
}
```

Comment: It may help to explain what you think the output should look like, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [LLVM Language Reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#simple-constants):

> Floating point constants Floating point constants use standard decimal
>   notation (e.g. 123.421), exponential notation (e.g. 1.23421e+2), or a
>   more precise hexadecimal notation (see below). **The assembler requires
>   the exact decimal value of a floating-point constant.** For example, the
>   assembler accepts 1.25 but rejects 1.3 because 1.3 is a repeating
>   decimal in binary. Floating point constants must have a floating point
>   type.

And also

> When using the hexadecimal form, constants of types half, float, and
>   double are represented using the 16-digit form shown above (which
>   matches the IEEE754 representation for double);